# Passing multiple parameters to SQL stored procedure PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute a stored procedure on my SQL DB by PHP. I saw an example of how to pass only one parameter into a stored procedure.
How should I send both parameters? user and psw?

```
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, array("UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pwd_db, "Database"=>$db));

 if($conn == false)
 {
     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
 }
 //prepare the storedprocedure
 $outputStoredProcedure = 1;
 $storedProcedureCall = "{call Login_Software( ?, ?)}";

 $arrPar = array();
 $arrPar = array($email,$password);

 $params = array(
     array($arrPar,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
     array($outputStoredProcedure, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT)
 );


 $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$storedProcedureCall,$params);
 if($stmt === false)
 {
     echo "Falhou ao executar a storedprocedure\n";
     die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }

 sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

by the end of the code, the `$stmt` is false and the error printing prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
            [1] => -16
            [code] => -16
            [2] => An invalid PHP type for parameter 0 was specified.
            [message] => An invalid PHP type for parameter 0 was specified.
        )

)
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: $stmt is false and I get an error saying there's an invalid PHP type for parameter 0.